# How do I express a type class constraint on the return value of a type class member in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Let's say I have the following types:

```
data State = State { ... }               -- exact structure is not relevant
data Message = Message { ... }           -- exact structure is not relevant

class Response a where
  messages :: a -> State -> [Message]
```

Now, I would like to create a new class `Query`, which demands that there is a method `query` that, when applied to an instance of `Query` and a `State`, returns some object which is an instance of `Response`, but this fails to compile:

```
class (Response b) => Query where        -- Compile error on b: "Not in scope: type variable b"
  query :: a -> State -> b
```

Is there a way for me to express in the `Query` class that I don't care which type the `query` method returns, as long as it instantiates the `Response` class?

Comment: This is nearly an instance of the existential typeclass pattern. `Response` should not be a class -- `data Response = Response { messages :: State -> [Message] }` is the correct model.  After this change, your question evaporates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add this to the type signature of the function:

```
class Query a where
  query :: Response b => a -> State -> b
```

Note however that this means it can return *any* `b` that is of a type that is an instance of `Response`.

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I was looking for :)

Then I'm getting type inference problems elsewhere in my application, where it fails to deduce the type of  `b`, but I'll have to get back with a new question if I don't manage to solve that...

Comment: @TomasAschan Double check if you actually need a class. If you will only have a single instance, you probably do not need the class. If you do need a class for this, you probably will need either type families or fundeps to make `b` deducible from `a`.

Comment: The use case is to enable implementing new features simply by creating instances of the requisite classes, so I will have multiple instances. (Basically, instantiate `Query` to provide `query :: a -> b`, and `Response` to provide `messages :: b -> [Message]`; there will be many instances of both `Query` and `Response`, but one-to-one mappings between them.) However, I might be able to re-structure my classes so that they are a little fewer and therefore don't have so many interdependencies...